# How to build a function on the fly in java?

Tags: java

I'm parsing a text file that is being mapped to some java code like such:

```
public void eval(Node arg)
    {
        if(arg.data.equals("rand"))
        {
            moveRandomly();
        }
        else if(arg.data.equals("home"))
        {
            goHome();
        }
            else if(arg.data.equals("iffood"))
    {
        ifFoodHere(arg.left, arg.right);
    }//snip..
```

This is going to need to be re-evaluated about a thousand times and I'd rather not have to traverse the whole thing every time.  Is there any way to make this traversal once and then have it be a function that is called every other time?

Answer (score 3):

You could make a Map of Runnables:

```
Map<String, Runnable> methods = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
methods.put("rand", new Runnable() 
{
    public void run()
    {
        moveRandomly();
    }
});
...
```

then in your method

```
public void eval(Node arg)
{
    Runnable command = methods.get(arg.data);
    command.run();
}
```

Comment: I think you mean Callable? If he does Runnable then each command will run in a separate thread, which is going to be very different from what the original code does.

Comment: Callable<T> runs in a separate thread too.  It returns a value of type T; Runnable does not.

Comment: Runnable only runs in a separate thread if I start it in a new thread though, right? You could use whatever class you want. He could even make his own class with a method that takes Node as a parameter so he can access the other data on the node, as he expressed might be something he wants.

Comment: @Joel - Correct, both Runnable and Callable require a Thread to start.

Comment: Most of the API docs for `Runnable` talk about threads. Then the last sentence says there isn't really a contract for the interface. I suggest using a meaningful interface for the task.

Comment: A `Runnable` is related to Threads because Threads use Runnables. But that doesn't mean you have to use a Runnable ONLY when using Threads. `Runnable`is simply an interface with one method called `run`. Hense: `Runnable`. I was just using it as an example anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Create an anonymous inner class.

Something like:

```
public Callable<Void> eval(Node arg)
{
  if(arg.data.equals("rand"))
  {
    return new Callable<Void>{ public Void call() { moveRandomly(); return null; } };
  }
  ...
}

Callable<Void> f = eval(a);
f.call();
```

Comment: The eval function is recursively called through children.  Does this change how this might work?

Comment: You can call a callable which was returned by an recursive eval in the  callable you create.
ps. Sounds like a tongue twister. :)

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.Callable`? Ergh. Push the boat: Write the three lines of code for a meaningful interface.

Comment: I said nothing about 'java.util.concurrent'. Just some 'Callable'.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the arguments/commands you can expect, i might do it like this:

```
enum Args {
  home, rand, iffood;

  private Method method;

  private Args () {
    try {
      this.method = Commands.class.getMethod(this.name(), Node.class);
    } catch (final Exception e) {}
  }
  public void invoke (final Node args)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
      InvocationTargetException {
    this.method.invoke(null, args);
  }
  public static Args valueOf (final Node arg) {
    return valueOf(arg.data);
  }
  public static void eval (final Node arg)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
      InvocationTargetException {
    valueOf(arg).invoke(arg);
  }
}
```

Command implementations are:

```
class Commands {    
  public static void home (final Node arg) {
    goHome(); // Call the implementation
    // or simply make these bodies the implementations.
  }
  public static void iffood (final Node arg) {
    ifFoodHere(arg.left, arg.right);
  }    
  public static void rand (final Node arg) {
    moveRandom();
  }
  //...
}
```

your eval() then becomes, simply:

```
try {
  Args.eval(arg);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // Handle unknown arg.data
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `enum` approach... but you can simplify further, each enum could have an `apply(final Node arg)` method that is defined separately for each enum. Then you don't need the separate Commands class or the use of reflection.